# OpenCV Error: No GPU support on windows vs2013&opencv249

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

My computer have the opencv2.4.9 for windows and I check the bin documents.It contains  "opencv_gpu249.dll" and "opencv_gpu249d.dll" and I also add the .lib to linker,but it doesn't work.Someone know how to deal with it ?
Another problem is OpenGL support,it's as same as the first one (I think）.
I don't want to rebuild opencv.

Comment: try a `cerr << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;` to see, what support was compiled into the opencv libs (the pre-built ones are bare-metal, no gpu/ocl/opencl support)